# Twitter API rate limit is per user per API or all API

Tags: twitter

I am new in Twitter API and not sure about twitter API rate limit work for per user per API or per user all API.
For example-
I am using two API 
GET followers/ids
GET friends/ids

As per twitter API documentation 15 hit per window of 15 minute for above urls.

My Question is : 
I can hit two API with same user 15 times each or only 15 hits allowed within 15 minute window for both API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The rate limits are per-endpoint, so you can make 15 calls in every 15 minute window to `followers/ids`, and also 15 calls in every 15 minute window to `friends/ids`.